# Meaning of 'pound' in "felt a fury that was not his own pound through his body"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Harry had given a cry of pain; his scar had burned again as something flashed across his mind like a bright light on water. He saw a large shadow and felt a fury that was not **his own pound** through his body, violent and brief as an electric shock.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

What does 'pound' mean in this context? I've looked it up in [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pound). But I don't know which definition fits.

Comment: The sentence would have been clearer with a few commas: "... felt a fury, that was not his own, pound through his body..." - I'm not sure if this is used in English, though. "Pound" is a verb: to pound = to knock, hammer, ...

Comment: Upvote this comment if you too came to this question mainly out of curiosity of whether the asker inadvertently asked about something X-rated. ;-)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Adding commas changes the meaning of the sentence:  As written (with "not his own" as a defining clause), the fact that the fury is not Harry's is a mandatory and emphasised part of the sentence.  With the commas (with "not his own" as a non-defining clause), it becomes an optional part of the sentence.  The point of the sentence is specifically that the fury **isn't** Harry's (but rather Voldemort's), instead of just being that Harry felt some fury - so commas are inappropriate.

Comment: @Chronocidal - That's a really important point, proving that an analysis of the syntax alone gets one only part of the way to an understanding of what the sentence is about.  The syntax says: "He felt a fury [xxx]... pound through his body."  But your comment adds a critical piece of information: that the xxx bit - **Voldemort's fury!** - is really the essential part of the sentence, and completely alters the reader's understand of what is happening in the story.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Disagree completely. Commas would make this harder to read not easier. One of the marks of a good writer is _not_ overusing commas.

Comment: @only_pro I suspect it is a matter of habit whether it makes harder or not - I grew up with strict, grammatical punctuation, so it feels natural to me, However, I don't think the question was about writing skills, but about meaning, and I would suggest that grammatical commas are a good tool for highlighting the structure of a sentence. That said, a tool is only useful if you know how to use it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The term "pound" in this instance means to pulsate or throb.  The sentence could have been written:

> "He felt ... fury ... throb through his body".

or

> "He felt ... fury ... pulse through his body".

We often refer to blood "pounding" in a person's veins when a person is angry or fearful, because of the faster and harder heartbeat that is created by anger or fear.  The sentence above has an implied or sub-textual reference to a pounding heart or blood pounding through the veins of the person who is experiencing fury.

See [definition of verb "to pound"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pound).

Comment: But 'Pound' is used as a noun in the quote.

Comment: The author of the Harry Potter is noted for her sometimes careless writing.

Comment: @dan - I don't understand your comment. The only noun I see in that specific part of the sentence is "fury".  I parse the sentence as "[He saw a large shadow] - and - [felt a fury ...  pound through his body].  Do you parse it differently?

Comment: @TechnoCat Oh! I parsed the sentence wrongly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dan - That's a relief!  I wondered whether the sentence was like one of those visual tricks that change from being a rabbit to a lady in a hat, depending on which way you look at it!  :)

Comment: @TechnoCat I parsed it like: [felt a fury] [that was not his own pound] [through his body,]

Comment: Yes there is a tiny pause after 'not his own', without which, the sentence is hard to understand.  It could do with a comma there (almost!). 'He felt a fury, that was not his own, pound through his body'. 

Comment: @Jelila Adding commas would also require changing "that" to "which".

Comment: Why is that, @tkk? It sounds a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: @Jelila "Which" is the relative pronoun for non-defining clauses, while "That" is the relative pronoun for defining clauses.  Once you put the adjective clause ("not his own") between commas or brackets, you are saying that is *additional* information, and no longer absolutely necessary to define the noun ("fury").  As such, it moves from being a defining clause (i.e. the fury not being his own is *mandatory* for the sentence, requiring "that") to being a non-defining clause (i.e. the fury not being his own is *optional* for the sentence, requiring "which").

Comment: @Jelila As such, adding the commas makes a subtle (but **meaningful**) change to the sentence - reducing the importance of the fury **not** being Harry's - which, in context, was the whole point of the paragraph!  Correctly parsed, "a fury that was not his own" is the entire noun.

Comment: Thank-you @Chronocidal. Great explanation.  Yes, I would actually not put a comma in. That’s why I said ‘it could do with a comma there - almost!)

Answer (score 47):

You parsed it in error.  It's not

```
(not)   felt 
(not)      a fury  
(not)         that is not his own pound
(not)      through his body
```

The noun is not "pound" being modified by "fury".
It is "fury" being modified by "pound".

```
felt 
   a fury  
      that is not his own
      pound
         through his body
```

"Pound" is what the fury is *doing*. It's an action. Note that two phrases are modifying "fury": *"that is not his own"* and *"pound"*.

If we simplify the sentence as much as possible by removing modifying phrases (except pound), we get

> He saw a shadow and felt a fury pound.

Or simpler,

> He saw a shadow and felt a fury.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with your final simplification. Yes, the two sentences have similar meanings, but it could be misconstrued to show that you could drop _any_ verb that came after fury and keep a similar meaning. E.g., if the sentence were "He saw a shadow and felt his fury _abate_." it would not be a valid simplification to drop "abate".

Comment: @ChrisBouchard I would say you should disagree with every simplification, as every one changes meaning.  What's more, all of them are essential to a YA book.  I agree, the last one takes it further than the others, it's only there to illustrate how very simple the sentence is structurally, when all the modifiers are removed.

Answer (score 4):

"pound" is a verb form of "to pound" here.  It is the same construct as "I felt a bee sting me".  The core part means "He felt a fury pound through his body, a fury that was not his own".  I'd use "rush" instead of "pound" here maybe, because furies tend not to move in one's body in much of a pounding manner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Harper provides an excellent technical analysis. For simplicity, the problem of comprehension can also be resolved by the minimal use of punctuation for clarification: "He saw a large shadow and felt a fury that was not his own, pound through his body".

I have done work translating German technical documents into English. As a result, I would not want to translate an English document into German.

Comment: *He saw a large shadow and felt a fury, that was not his own, pound through his body* Either two commas or none.

Comment: I'd want to lose the "that was" in the version with commas @JanDoggen

Answer (score 1):

Pound = heartbeat

As in the hearts making a pounding from within.